# Automatic handling of session token with boto3 and MFA

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have my `.aws/credentials` set as

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = [key]
aws_secret_access_key = [secret! Shh!]
```

and `.aws/config`

```
[profile elevated]
role_arn = [elevated role arn]
source_profile = default
mfa_serial = [my device arn]
```

With the `credentials` and `config` files set up like that, [`boto3` will](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#assume-role-provider)

> automatically make the corresponding AssumeRole calls to AWS STS on your behalf. It will handle in
>   memory caching as well as refreshing credentials as needed

so that when I use something like

```py
session = boto3.Session(profile_name = "elevated")
```

in a longer function, all I have to do is input my MFA code immediately after hitting "enter" and everything runs and credentials are managed independent of my input. This is great. I like that when I need to assume a role in another AWS account, `boto3` handles all of the calls to `sts` and all I have to do is babysit.

What about when I *don't* want to assume another role? If I want to do things directly as my `user` as a member of the group to which my user is assigned? Is there a way to let `boto3` automatically handle the credentials aspect of that?

[I see that I can hard-code into a fx my `aws_access_key_id` and `..._secret_...`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981950/how-to-specify-credentials-when-connecting-to-boto3-s3?rq=1) , but is there a way to force `boto3` into handling the session tokens by just using the `config` and `credentials` files?

[Method 2 in this answer looked promising](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51275071/4351030) but it also seems to rely on using the AWS CLI to input and store the keys/session token prior to running a Python script and *still* requires hard-coding variables into a CLI.

Is there a way to make this automatic by using the `config` and `credentials` files that doesn't require having to manually input AWS access keys and handle session tokens?

Comment: You can get a session using the `default` profile by not specifying anything (`session = boto3.Session(profile_name = "elevated")`) - is there a reason why that would not work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the application on EC2, you can attach roles via EC2 Roles.
On your code, you may dynamically get the credentials depending on which role you attach.

```
session = boto3.
credentials = session.get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials()

access_key = credentials.access_key
secret_key = credentials.secret_key
token = credentials.token
```

you may also want to use botocore.credentials.RefreshableCredentials to refresh your token once in a while

Comment: This only works if the application is on EC2? What if it's just running on my local machine?